# Oracle DB Client 19c install error -> INS-32103 Specified Oracle Home user does not match with existing Home user

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am trying to install Oracle Database Client 19c. From what I understand, if I want to connect SQL Server Management Studio to an Oracle database, I need to install this client. So I already installed the "Instant Client" without any problems. I was able to test the connection under the "ODBC -> Oracle driver"

[image]

Below are my installation steps of the Database client

1. select "Administrator"
   [image]
2. For selecting a Home User, I've tried using an Existing Windows user (local user), and also I've tried "Use Windows Built-in Account"
   [image]
3. I selected the Oracle base and software location. Then I clicked "Next" and it gives me the error about the Home User does not match with existing Home user.
   [image]

Can anyone help me figure out why I am getting this error and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Is c:\oracle empty?  Or what happens when you install into a non-existing folder so that the installer has to create it?  Are you running the installer as admin?  Finally, you might find the instant client easier - its just unzip and go

Comment: Hi @ConnorMcDonald, c:\oracle is not empty. It's where I installed the instant client to. so it is at C:\oracle\instantclient_19_3. Instant Client installed just fine for me. I'm trying to connect SQL Server Management studio to an Oracle database on another server that I have credentials too. See the screenshot on my successful test connection above. I did run the "Oracle Database Client 19c" as an admin. I will try to install the "Oracle Database Client 19c" to a different folder that is blank and see if that fixes the "Home user" error I am getting.

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald, when I try to perform the install of the "Oracle Database Client 19c" into a blank directory, I get an error message that says "the selected Oracle home is outside of the Oracle base". I really don't know how to get pass the "Home user" error. Since I have the Instant Client already installed, do you know How I can use it to connect to the Oracle DB and run queries? I don't see a program in windows called "Instant Client" to open even though I already have it installed.

Comment: I'm no SSMS expert, but once you have Oracle connectivity working via the ODBC driver, would you not just choose that as a data source and be off and running?

Answer (score 5):

This can also be caused by an inventory entry still existing for the oracle home, especially if you are installing/deinstalling on the same machine. To test for that, use a different home and try the install, anything that will not match the previous home. I was testing my install process so I just ended up deleting the inventory files from C:\program files(x86)\Oracle, but you can also detach the home.

Comment: I was trying to re-install the Oracle Database Client 19c. and I got the same "specified oracle home user does not match with existing home user", but removing the C:\program files(x86)\Oracle directory then running the installation worked.